# Oracle pl/sql preferred way of providing environment specific parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is the preferred way to provide parameters (configuration) for pl/sql packages?
Having different environments (test, qa, prd)  there is a need for specifying values which should be set appropriately for each environment. Once the package is installed these values won't change.
I'm looking for a way which preferably allows having the same code for every environment.

Comment: What kind of parameters? Session level? Then you could just use `IF-ELSE` construct.

Answer (score 3):

You can use configuration table with key-value pairs. Insert different values for different environments and load these values where needed in code into PL/SQL variables.

Comment: +1, but remember to use multiple value columns, one for each type.  Most people implement this by saving everything as a string, which causes problems later.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify the session level parameters, then you could use an `IF-ELSE` construct in your PL/SQL code. And then, you need to use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** to execute the **ALTER SESSION** statements.

To find the current database name. you could query **name** from *v$database**:

```
SQL> SELECT name FROM v$database;

NAME
---------
ORCL
```

You could store this in a local variable and then have an `IF-ELSE` logic to modify the session parameters at run time.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
---------
11-MAY-15

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_db_name VARCHAR2(20);
  3  BEGIN
  4    SELECT NAME INTO v_db_name FROM v$database;
  5    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Current database is : '||V_DB_NAME);
  6    IF v_db_name = 'ORCL' THEN
  7      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[alter session set nls_date_format='MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS']';
  8    ELSIF v_db_name = 'QA' THEN
  9      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS']';
 10    ELSE
 11      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS']';
 12    END IF;
 13  END;
 14  /
Current database is : ORCL

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
-------------------
05/11/2015 14:24:26
```

So, you could add an `IF-ELSE` block to your existing **PL/SQL** code and use the **same code in all the environments**:

```
IF v_db_name = 'param1' THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[alter session set parameter='value1']';
ELSIF v_db_name = 'param2' THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[alter session set parameter='value2']';
ELSE
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[alter session set parameter='value3']';
END IF;
```

To use a parameter value globally across all packages, you could have a look at **[global context variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/app_context.htm#DBSEG011)**.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**

Using `sys_context` or something similar. This will allow you to use these parameters in SQL without performance losses as well. E.g. see [this article](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/05/05/user-defined-sys_context/) to get the functionality like that:

```
SELECT sys_context('sample_ctx','email') FROM dual
```

If you combine it with a `logon` trigger you should be able to set it in every new session.

**OPTION 2**

Another option is to use a global array of these values in a specification of some package. The type of array should be something like

```
TYPE population_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
```

This should be initialized inside of the package body (pseudo code):

```
PACKAGE BODY ...
   ... -- functions etc
BEGIN
    -- initialization of your array
END PACKAGE BODY;
```

Then you are able to use it as my_params.my_array("my_parameter") and directly access the value.

The advantage of the option #2 is that it is stored in RAM and the value is obtained by a built-in array reader function. This also does not require any specific privileges (that's way better than OPTION 1) and also it does not read the table any time you wish to get a parameter. If you still like to store the parameters in some table you can still read it once when the session starts (this will be done automatically during the package initialization).

The disadvantage is that it is maybe harder to use the array in SQL processing.